# Asking tutorial for VB.NET Thread

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading

I have a class named TestClass

```
Public Class TestClass

    Private _Count As Integer


    Public ReadOnly Property Count() As Integer
        Get
            For i As Integer = 0 To 999999999
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            Next

            Return 100
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Form the main form, I call the class. Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tg As New TestClass
    MsgBox(tg.Count)

End Sub
```

When I call `tg.Count` from main form, the main form will become not responding. How to prevent my form from not responding. The user can access other menu rather than waiting for the result. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Use `BackgroundWorker` to run it in a worker thread. That will keep your GUI responding.
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/

Drag the `BackgroundWorker` componenet from the toolbox onto the form. Now, put your counter loop within the `BackgroundWorker_DoWork` event handler, which is autogenerated for you. All you need to do now is to call `RunWorkerAsync` on it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I know how to use the background worker. But all i want to how the value return to it's caller. Have you ever see the SMS Library. When I call msgbox(objGSM.IMEI), I can access other menu in the application without waiting the object processing the result.

Comment: You can return the value directly to the GUI object, and enclose it in a try ... catch block. Cross-thread calls wont make a fuss then. I still dont understand your issue.

Comment: +1: I did take it upon myself to improve the formatting and grammar for you though.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is looping from  0 to 999999999 and delaying 100ms every loop which is halting that current thread.  A better solution would be to use a timer, check for your completed condition and restart the timer if necessary.  This way, your main form thread will always be responsive.

Comment: I know how to use the background worker. But all i want to how the value return to it's caller. Have you ever see the SMS Library. When I call msgbox(objGSM.IMEI), I can access other menu in the application without waiting the object processing the result.